# ImGui read then return to const char

Tags: c++, imgui

Hello i haven't done programming in a while so i started learning again and decided to do read/write process memory, currently struggling with this section here.

```
if (ImGui::Button("Get Coal"))
{
    ReadProcessMemory(cGame, (byte*)0x1467C87, buffer, buffer.length, NULL);
    ImGui::Text(buffer);
}
```

i found my address and want to read from the address however i can't figure out how to return the value. Not only do i get an error with buffer.lengh but also using buffer as a const char.

Comment: Hi there, please provide a [mcve]. This includes any errors, the excepted behaviour and remove ImGui if it is not relevant to the question. My guess is that `buffer` is an array or a pointer, so it does not have `length` member.

Comment: The error i get is buffer.Length must have a class type, and text(buffer) i get argument of type "const char**" is incompatible with parameter of tpe "const char*".
The idea is it should read and address and buffer should return the amount of coal. That stored in that offset.

if i add a number like 10 its fine but i still can't get that value and use it as a const char* to display in a label

Comment: Please really make the minimal example, I still do not know what type `buffer` really has. If it is `const char**` then it is an array of pointers, it does not have `.length` member. You can use `std::vector` with its `.data()` and `.size()` methods.